# Does STAB affect the chance to inflict a status effect?

Tags: pokemon-series

I know that a STAB bonus applies to type-based damage done by a Pokemon of the same type, ex. a Water type Pokemon deals more damage with Water type moves.

However, do STAB bonuses affect the chance to inflict a negative status effect? Let's say a Fire type Pokemon knows Ember, which can cause the Burn status effect. Is this chance increased by the attacking Pokemon being a Fire type?

Furthermore, if a Pokemon is weak to Fire, is there a greater chance of the Burn status effect being inflicted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The only ways to affect extra effects are Serene Grace and Shield Dust, which respectively double chances of the user's extra effects activating, and block any extra effect from activating on the user.

The only way that "STAB" affects any non-damaging move is that Toxic is unable to miss when used by a Poison-type Pokémon, just like using Lock-On or when having the ability No Guard.